# How can i paginate table

Tags: react-native

I have the following code to display data from json file, i have more that 500 records i want to display 10 records per page. Here is my project in [code pen][1] . I tried react-pagination library but that doesn't work. what is the best way to do this? Open to use any library recommended -- i tried almost all of them.

here is how my code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are a hundred different ways of doing it, but just to teach the idea of the mechanics, here is a very manual version:

```js
  {this.state.filteredData
    .slice(this.state.activePage * 10, (this.state.activePage + 1) * 10)
    .map(results => ( ...
  ))}

.....

  {/*Pagination goes here */}

  <button onClick={() => {this.setState({activePage: this.state.activePage - 1})}} >
    prev</button>
  <button onClick={() => {this.setState({activePage: this.state.activePage + 1})}} >
    next</button>
```

That is, you take only a slice of the data before mapping it into DOM elements, and the buttons for advancing or going back just select the slice by setting the `activePage` state variable you already had.

Comment: you need to set `activePages` to 0 in your state or add the buttons I mentioned and then click the "prev" bunch of times until you are back at page 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something along the lines of an `index` and `offset` and then create chunks of your array.

Give this a try:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import cardData from "./response.json";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const offset = 5;
    console.log(cardData);
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      index: 0,
      offset,
      chunks: this.chunkArray(cardData.data.Table, offset)
    };
  }

  chunkArray(inputArray, chunkSize){
    console.log("inputArray:: ", inputArray);
    const results = [];  
    while (inputArray.length) {
      results.push(inputArray.splice(0, chunkSize));
    }
    console.log("results:: ", results);
    return results;
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      index
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.chunks);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.chunks && this.state.chunks[this.state.index].map(results => (
          <div className="col-sm-3">
            <h3>
              {results.first_name} {results.last_name}
            </h3>
            <h3>{results.manager}</h3>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6"> {results.Department}</div>
            </div>

            <a
              to={{ pathname: `/cards/${results.id}`, state: results }}
              className={`card-wrapper restore-${results.id}`}
              href={`/cards/${results.id}`}
            >
              View Detail
            </a>
          </div>
        ))}
        <br />
        { this.state.chunks && this.state.chunks.map((item, index) => <button onClick={()  => this.handleClick(index)}>{index + 1}</button>) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Code Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pagination-eg?file=index.js) for your ref.

Comment: what is Hello.js?

Comment: it worked Perfect!!! but i need you to do me a favor i would to replace instead of `Carddata.data.table` i like to replace it by the api reponse i used this code `componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('URL', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'api-key': 'api-key'
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.successShow(response);
            })
 
    }
    successShow(response) {
        this.setState({
            filteredData: response.data.data.Table
        });

    }` how can i do that?

Comment: added at the bottom of my code on how to get api data to display data i used `and to diplay data from api reposnse`enter code here`   something like 

    `{this.state.filteredData.map((results, i) => (
                  <div className="col-sm-12" >                      
                    {results.first_name} {results.last_name}                                   
                                ))`

Comment: I've actually updated my Sample StackBlitz to accommodate for fetching the data from an API and then populating it on the UI. Please have a look. It also handles varying page sizes. I think you would want to implement that as a feature so I added it just in case. :)

Comment: Oh you the best! Thanks SiddAjmera, Please don't delete it, i might need that later

Comment: it messed up my search and filter i get `TypeError: chunk[stateIndex].map is not a function` when i search.. please help

Comment: I had search functionality in here can you add it to you solution so that i can check where the problem is coming from https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gates-2xkl7

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hooks, this will work otherwise it can be easily adapted.  Basically, just store the index of where you are and then get the data you need based on that index:

```
const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
const PAGE_SIZE = 10;
const tableData = cardData.data.Table.slice(index, index + PAGE_SIZE);

const table = {tableData.map(results => (
          <div className="col-sm-3">
                <h3>
                  {results.first_name} {results.last_name}
                </h3>
                <h3 >{results.manager}</h3>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6"> {results.Department}</div>
                </div>

                <Link
                  to={{ pathname: `/cards/${results.id}`, state: results }}
                  className={`card-wrapper restore-${results.id}`}
                >
                  View Detail
                </Link>
            </div>
        ))}

const navigation = (
    <div>
        <div disabled={index <= 0 ? true : false} onClick={() => setIndex(index - PAGE_SIZE)}>Prev</div>
        <div disabled={index <= cardData.data.Table.length ? true : false} onClick={() => setIndex(index + PAGE_SIZE)}>Next</div>
    </div>
);
```